# Return specific item from json file and print to screen

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a JSON file that I would like to loop through the information and show certain items that I need. When I leave some of the information out it throws a error that fields are missing.

Example of data need to be entered:

```
package ID number
delivery address
delivery deadline 
delivery city 
delivery zip code 
package weight 
delivery status (e.g., delivered, in route)
```

desired output:

```
ID: 28, Address: 2835 Main St, deadline: EOD (or whatever it is), city: SLC, zip: 12345, weight: 10, delivery status: delivered at 8:35am
```

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "address": "195 W Oakland Ave",
        "city": "Salt Lake City",
        "state": "UT",
        "zip": 84115,
        "deadline": {
            "hour": 10,
            "minute": 30
        },
        "kg": 21,
        "notes": "Is Being Delivered"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "address": "2530 S 500 E",
        "city": "Salt Lake City",
        "state": "UT",
        "zip": 84106,
        "deadline": {
            "hour": 17,
            "minute": 0
        },
        "kg": 44,
        "notes": "Is Being Delivered"
    }

def main():
    print('Solution executed!')
    packageData = loadsJson(os.path.join(main_directory, 'packageTables.json'))
    allPackages = [Package(p['id'], p['address'], p['city'], p['state'], p['zip'], p['deadline'], p['kg'], 'IN_ROUTE') for p in packageData]
    [print(p) for p in allPackages]
    distanceData = loadsJson(os.path.join(main_directory, 'distanceTables.json'))

#Define main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
get_keys = itemgetter('id', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'deadline', 'kg')
with open("filename.json",'r') as f:
    packages = [Package(*get_keys(p), 'IN_ROUTE') for p in json.load(f)]
```

Also, I wouldn't use list comprehensions for one liner printing or any throw away loop, it's inefficient and unnecessary. Just use a regular loop. Hint: *(you can do it in one line too)*

```
#bad
[print(p) for p in packages]
#good
for p in packages: print(p)
```

Even better for printing, just use star-unpacking:

```
print(*packages)
```

Results:

```
#I used collections.namedtuple for example packages so obviously they may look different..
[Package(id=1, address='195 W Oakland Ave', city='Salt Lake City', state='UT', zip=84115, deadline={'hour': 10, 'minute': 30}, kg=21, status='IN_ROUTE'),
 Package(id=2, address='2530 S 500 E', city='Salt Lake City', state='UT', zip=84106, deadline={'hour': 17, 'minute': 0}, kg=44, status='IN_ROUTE')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Json:

```
 [   {
        "id": 1,
        "address": "195 W Oakland Ave",
        "city": "Salt Lake City",
        "state": "UT",
        "zip": 84115,
        "deadline": {
            "hour": 10,
            "minute": 30
        },
        "kg": 21,
        "notes": "Is Being Delivered"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "address": "2530 S 500 E",
        "city": "Salt Lake City",
        "state": "UT",
        "zip": 84106,
        "deadline": {
            "hour": 17,
            "minute": 0
        },
        "kg": 44,
        "notes": "Is Being Delivered"
    }
 ]
```

Python:

```
import json

with open("file.json",'r') as f:
    var = json.load(f)
allPackages = [(p['id'], p['address'], p['city'], p['state'], p['zip'], p['deadline'], p['kg'], 'IN_ROUTE') for p in var]
[print(p) for p in allPackages]
```

Output:

```
(1, '195 W Oakland Ave', 'Salt Lake City', 'UT', 84115, {'hour': 10, 'minute': 30}, 21, 'IN_ROUTE')
(2, '2530 S 500 E', 'Salt Lake City', 'UT', 84106, {'hour': 17, 'minute': 0}, 44, 'IN_ROUTE')
```

I don't know the structure of your class Package, but it would recommend using json module, this way I was able to extract all the requested info from the json into python. Maybe if you could post the definition or constructor of the class. Hope this helps.